# How To collect iPhone App information

Tags: iphone, app-store, appdata

There are some apps that introduce other popular applications. I'm really surprised that when I change the cost of my application, the introducing app shows the new cost of mine really quickly.

How can this be possible? Is the developer collecting the data by hand, or is Apple providing all the information of their apps on the web somewhere?

Comment: One can see app descriptions in the browser. What can be seen in the browser is accessible in an app.

Comment: I already know that. Also I parsed some website to show some of information in my app. I meant a source which gives us all the application information in appstore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the [Affiliate Search API](http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html). Here's their [example for the Yelp app](http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=284910350), which includes a JSON parameter for price:

```
{
   ...
   "price":0.00,
   ...
}
```

Comment: This answer gave me a hint! So now I have to search a site(or url) that provide app id.